# How to give a refresh equal to Ctrl+ R in gwt web app?

Tags: java, gwt, page-refresh

In my web app I am changing locale in settings and I found out the locale change takes effect only after pressing `F5` button or `Ctrl + R`. I have tested different approaches to programmatically make equal refresh (one that changes locale), but no success on that. What is the programmatic equivalent to that refresh event?

I tried `Window.Location.reload();` with no desired effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F5 i.e Ctrl+R equivalent via GWT is `com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.Location.reload();`

1. Just ensure you are using the right [**Window**](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.Location.html) import.
2. Read reference for the [reload documentation](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.Location.html#reload%28%29).

Comment: Why I didn't believe first this would be the correct equivalent was that I called a `History.back();` after calling this `Window.Location.reload();` and I faced a "Please, don't eat from trash" problem described here: http://www.coderanch.com/t/120621/HTML-CSS-JavaScript/Waiting-Refresh . History call mixed things so that reload did not happen. Thanks SSR for confirming I was using correct function. Now my solution work brilliantly.