# Jquery mobile force reloading the same page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using jquery mobile 1.3.1 and jquery 1.9.1.
I'm trying to reload a page which is generated at serverside with a button-click event:

```js
$('a.force-reload').on('click', function(e) {
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  $.mobile.loadPage( url, {
     transition: "slide",
     allowSamePageTransition: true
  });
  alert("test");
});
```

When I click the button with the class "force-reload" I can see the "test"-Alertmessage. But the page is not reloading. What's going wrong in my code?

Comment: The page is a `URL.html` or hashtag page `#page`?

Comment: It is a url like "/mypage" (generated at serverside from symfony 2). It's not containing the hostname.

Comment: Replace `allowSame.....` with `reloadPage: true`.

Comment: I have already tried this. The buttons gets the ui-active-state class but the page is not reloaded. And it doesn't matter if I use "/mypage" or "http://dev.localhost/mypage". When I hardcode a typo error "http://deV.localhost/mypage", then it works. But that's not a solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same looking situation and I would point out two different aspects for seeking the solution:

**#1:**

What other code you have around this code? This case [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292110/how-to-give-a-refresh-equal-to-ctrl-r-in-gwt-web-app) is my situation, where the surrounding code was causing `History.back()` event on leaving the page, which cancelled the direction to the fresh page.

Please check the other code on that screen, that there is not a close event listener or handler somewhere, that causes the similar effect.

**#2:**

Also, I have tested, that at least `Window.Location.reload();` should make the thing if the problem happens to be on your given code.

**References:**

[1] [How to give a refresh equal to Ctrl+ R in gwt web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292110/how-to-give-a-refresh-equal-to-ctrl-r-in-gwt-web-app)

Comment: If the alert is coming to the screen, the most possible cause is that the JavaScript fails somehow, because otherwise the code should lead you to new page before the execution comes to that point. My help #2 is then the most probable thing I would test first.